# How to display JTree file in JTextArea

Tags: java, swing, jtree, jtextarea

In my program i have a `JTree` which is being populated by a number of folders and files. When you select a file in the `JTree` I want that file to display in the `JTextArea`.

I no you can use `getLastSelectedPathComponent()` to get the last selected item from the `JTree` which can be used to get the chosen file from the tree but this is then a node of the tree... is there a way to get the text from this node like using a `FileReader` and a `BufferReader`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not directly. What you will need to do:

1. Store the file name (with path if you want to make your life easier) in the node. Extend `DefaultMutableTreeNode` for this.
2. When a node is selected, read the file name from it.
3. Use the usual Java IO API to read the file as text

Comment: what do you mean when you say 'Store the file name in the node'? do you do this when the JTree is created?

Comment: What kind of node type do you use to build your tree?

Comment: Just a normal DefaultMutableTreeNode

Comment: Create a new type `FileTreeNode extends DefaultMutableTreeNode` with a new field `File file`. Set the file when you create the node.

Answer (score 3):

I would put `File` objects in the tree and use a cell renderer to show (render) them as required.

See [File Browser GUI](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/4446/file-browser-gui) for an example.  The example also demonstrates how to retrieve details of the selected file or directory.  It uses the `Desktop` class to display(/print/edit) files.

[image]

Comment: +1 for a great answer as well!! but its just a bit more then i wanted and i think it would take a bit of time to get it working how i would want it so i went with the answer Aaron Digulla gave